# Split path from behind

Tags: python

how can i split the path to variable?
I always need the top directory and the second from the top and the rest as variables.

```
example:
path = '/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1' 


is needed:
dir0 = /home/user/archive/aa/bb
dir1 = data
dir2 = datadir1

example:
path = '/home/user/archive/data2/datadir2' 


is needed:
dir0 = /home/user/archive
dir1 = data2
dir2 = datadir2
```

so here is counted from the beginning:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = '/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1'
path1 = Path(path).parents[3]
print(path1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `os.path.split()`, which will separate a path into the [directory] and [file]. We can call it once to get the file's path, then call it again on the directory the file's in to get that directory and its own parent:

```
import os

path = '/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1' 
path, dir2 = os.path.split(path)
dir0, dir1 = os.path.split(path)

print(dir0)  # /home/user/archive/aa/bb
print(dir1)  # data
print(dir2)  # datadir1
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that `Path.parents` does not support slicing and negative indexing

Answer (score 0):

Another easy approach without any kind of additional libraries and assuming that you know the delimeter:

```
def split_path(path, delim = "/"):
    path_vals = path.split(delim)    # separate the string by delimeter
    return (
        delim.join(path_vals[:-2]),  # Join all but last 2 elements /w delimeter
        path_vals[-2],  # get second to last directory
        path_vals[-1]   # get last directory
    )

[print(x) for x in split_path('/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1')]
[print(x) for x in split_path('/home/user/archive/data2/datadir2')]

# /home/user/archive/aa/bb
# data
# datadir1
# /home/user/archive
# data2
# datadir2
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to re-implement well-tested, cross-platform code from the std library

Comment: Totally. This is more of a quick thing that you can do in a scripting scenario. Probably don't want to make public code with this.

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way using .split()

```py
path = '/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1'

dir2 = path.split('/')[-1]
dir1 = path.split('/')[-2]
dir0 = path.replace(dir2, '').replace(dir1, '').replace('//', '')
```

and here's that way in a function:

```py
def path(path):
    return path.split('/')[-1], path.split('/')[-2], path.replace(dir2, '').replace(dir1, '').replace('//', '')

print(path('/home/user/archive/aa/bb/data/datadir1'))
```